# Can you buy things "for cheap"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, dialects

The first line of this [news story](http://www.stuff.co.nz/technology/8214295/Pentagon-plans-satellite-surgery/) says:

> Call it space grave robbery for a cause: imagine scavenging defunct communication satellites for their valuable parts and recycling them to build brand new ones **for cheap**.

I've heard people use that "for cheap" construction before, but thought it was dialectal (mid-to-northern English). I was surprised to see it in an NZ publication.

Why does that almost pass grammatical muster, whereas "for expensive" (for example) really stinks?

Comment: I agree that it is not British Standard English. It would instead be _on the cheap_.

Comment: It's a common enough expression here in NZ.

Comment: @James Jiao: Is it? I haven't heard it here before. Do you think it is a British import? I wonder if that construction is used in any Asian or PI languages.

Comment: @Kyudos Yes it is. On the contrary, Barrie's *on the cheap* sounds quite alien to me, though I would understand it. (I take it you meant Asian). Your suggestion is possible. I am not an expert on Polynesian languages, but neither Japanese nor Chinese have this literal *for cheap* construction. It really depends on how one translates things. I still consider British import to be the most likely source. But yes defintitely food for thought.

Comment: @James Jiao: _on the cheap_ is definitely a British English thing, common enough that almost anything in Britain can be done _on the cheap_.

Comment: You can buy something *for a song* (also a very nice expression). See http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+a+song.

Comment: @Pantelis: Oooh! Can we all play? Me, I like to get my bargains [for buttons](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22get+it+for+buttons%22&oq=%22get+it+for+buttons%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.6745&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), unless they're already [as cheap as chips](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22cheap+as+chips%22&oq=%22cheap+as+chips%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.102903&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *Talk is cheap*! And, if something *costs a pretty penny*, don't *pay an arm and a leg* to get it!... drive a hard bargain! And so on... There are a great many idioms (and especially about money, prices and bargain).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with dialects or pidgins, but once you start mixing parts of speech, you might as well yell at the other person for saying it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google Books...

> [build them **cheaply**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22build%20them%20cheaply%22&oq=%22build%20them%20cheaply%22&gs_l=serp.3...6276.10570.1.11434.18.18.0.0.0.1.319.1502.15j2j0j1.18.0...0.0...1c.1.7Eui4syYiso&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):600 hits
>    [build them **cheap**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22build%20them%20cheap%22&oq=%22build%20them%20cheap%22&gs_l=serp.3...428596.428733.6.429054.2.2.0.0.0.0.99.177.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.88hmkCL2k8s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):294 hits
>    [build them **for cheap**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22build%20them%20for%20cheap%22&oq=%22build%20them%20for%20cheap%22&gs_l=serp.3...5307.11785.2.12231.8.8.0.0.0.0.90.503.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.JuQsrBQGnNM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):0 hits
>
> [buy them **cheaply**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22buy%20them%20cheaply%22&oq=%22buy%20them%20cheaply%22&gs_l=serp.3...5422.8455.5.8843.6.6.0.0.0.0.74.303.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.Sdqf7Do8zE4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):4750 hits
>    [buy them **cheap**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22buy%20them%20cheap%22&oq=%22buy%20them%20cheap%22&gs_l=serp.3...82569.83268.7.83924.4.4.0.0.0.1.194.403.3j1.4.0...0.0...1c.1.CNqabY-VIdE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):9980 hits
>    [buy them **for cheap**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22build%20brand%20new%20ones%20for%20cheap%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22buy%20them%20for%20cheap%22&oq=%22buy%20them%20for%20cheap%22&gs_l=serp.3...110398.111669.4.111980.4.4.0.0.0.0.63.212.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.Wuj027Eczc4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.d2k&fp=f0b2d06f0baf859d&biw=1253&bih=886):49 hits

As @bib says, *for cheap* may well be patterned after *for free*, where there's [also disagreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38161/is-the-phrase-for-free-correct) over "acceptable" usage. For me personally, *for cheap* doesn't "pass grammatical muster", but I have no problem with people using adjectival *cheap* instead of adverbial *cheaply*.

Comment: I agree on the mustering, unless the usage was intentionally jocular. I did say _almost_ pass!

Comment: @Kyudos: I thought it was quite a nice turn of phrase, and I figured echoing it back was a good way of light-heartedly acknowledging that. But I certainly agree with you that *build/buy for cheap* is a lot more acceptable than *for expensive*, even if it doesn't exactly come up to the gold standard (i.e. - *my* idea of "grammaticality"! :)

Comment: I would use 'for cheap' (UK) though I agree it doesn't make grammatical sense. It's just one of those things.

Comment: @Mynamite: Given the usage figures in my answer, I'd say it doesn't make *any* sense, let alone *grammatical* sense! But there's no danger of you being misunderstood, and I see you're UK-based, so I can safely say *"It's a free country, you can say what you like"*. But note that even [for free](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38166/2637) is considered "iffy" by many. Obviously it's pointless searching for *buy for free*, but it's worth noting *get it for cheap* has only 342 hits on Google Books, where *get it cheap* has 13800 (so your usage **will** stand out! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ...erm... I don't have a problem with 'for free' either. How would you personally say "We got in [to the concert] for free"? ie without paying.

Comment: @Mynamite: From Google Books - [I got in for free](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+got+in+for+free%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):142 results, [I got in free](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+got+in+free%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):627 results. I'd say it the same way most people do. Or, of course, I could go for [I got in for nothing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+got+in+for+nothing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but that's a different word completely (and only 78 results! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers An interesting and useful discussion, to which I don't have much constructive to add, but having talked about resultative constructions this weekend, I couldn't help but notice your adjectival/adverbial split. No, both cheap and cheaply are adverbial in this case. However, in _They sell them cheap_, cheap _is_ adjectival, just as in _They sold them damaged_.But _I bought them damaged_ involves a cognitive process quite different from the one involved in _I bought them cheap_.I didn't buy them SUCH that they were cheap;I bought them IN A WAY that they were cheap for me. Cheap-ly.

Comment: @Talia: Yeah - I know [it's being used adverbially](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/). But if you ask someone which is adjective and which is adverb out of *cheap* and *cheaply* you know what the answer will be. And obviously it's perfectly possible to use the "correct/regular" version and [*buy it **cheaply***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22buy+it+cheaply+from%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Your comment is useful, but I'm still happy with what I originally wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a spin off of *for free*, such as

> If you can't get it for free, at least get it *for cheap*.

It could be understood to mean

> get it for [a] cheap [price]

In either case, it is colloquial at best.  I have heard it as a slang expression in the US.

As to why it is less jarring than *for expensive*, I don't know. As an antonym, *for dear* might be arguably more acceptable (if only because it maintains the abbreviated, single syllable style), although I can't say I have heard it in the US.

Comment: I've heard it in from the Irish and the British also. It could perhaps be a hyper-correction of the adverb sense of *cheap* as in "I bought it cheap".

Comment: +1 for *get it for [a] cheap [price]*: suddenly everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

'for free' is incorrect; something is either 'free' or 'for nothing.' It just sounds normal because many people say it now.

Comment: How can it not be correct if many people say it?

Comment: People say "ain't", but that doesn't make it correct grammar.  People say "aren't I" but that doesn't make it correct grammar.