# "Sign up free" or "Sign up for free"

Tags: word-choice, differences

I've stumbled upon "Sign up free" and "Sign up for free" on different websites.

"Sign up free" makes no sense to me. Is it correct? Which one should I use on my website? Thanks.

Comment: Neither are grammatically correct sentences, but they have become everyday idiomatic expressions. A correct sentence would be 'Sign up, free of charge', which is the way that a conservative organisation would probably include it on a website.

Comment: free membership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine.

In "Sign up free."  "Sign up" is a phrasal verb, "free" is an adverb modifying it, and the whole thing is a perfectly grammatical imperative sentence.

"Sign up for free." is identical except that it uses the phrase "for free", which has been handled in another question: [Is the phrase "for free" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38161/is-the-phrase-for-free-correct)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a clickable link or a label:

- *Free sign-up*
- *Free registration*
- *Free enrollment*

If it's in the narrative, though, don't write "sign up free" because it's ungrammatical; instead write "for free."

Comment: "for free" is also ungrammatical.

Comment: "...free" can be considered a contraction of "...free of charge", which is not ungrammatical. "...for free" doesn't seem to make any sense.